# TediousJS Issues

Tags: sql, node.js, azure, azure-sql-database, tedious

We have a system with on premise NodeJS server and Azure SQL DB. We are using https://github.com/tediousjs. There are two issues that are frequently coming up. They are:

```
Error: Acquire Timeout Exceeded
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/opt/node/ios-services/node_modules/tedious-connection-pool/lib/connection-pool.js:191:41)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10) 'Unhandled Rejection at Promise' Promise {
  <rejected> Error: Acquire Timeout Exceeded
      at Timeout._onTimeout (/opt/node/ios-services/node_modules/tedious-connection-pool/lib/connection-pool.js:191:41)
      at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
      at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
      at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
      at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10) }
```

and

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
    at Object.callback (/opt/node/ios-services/model/dbExe.js:53:28)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/opt/node/ios-services/node_modules/tedious-connection-pool/lib/connection-pool.js:191:32)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10) 'Uncaught Exception thrown'
```

We tried to resolve the second issue by increasing the packet size. However it keeps repeating. Can someone point to exact solutions to solve these errors. I don;t see any solutions for these and hence this thread would be useful to a lot of people.

Comment: The term "Timeout" usually suggests a network connectivity problem. And since you seem to indicate the problem is sporadic, that's a further indication. Do you agree?

Comment: No network connectivity doesn't look like an issue!

Comment: How do you know?

Comment: The network team confirmed that its working fine.

Comment: Your timeout exception messages perhaps suggest otherwise. Sorry, I have nothing more to offer. I'm out!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'm also agree with what @robbpriestley said in the comment, it's a network connectivity problem, or in other words, network delay. I see the default value of `aquireTimeout` is 60 seconds, as the figure below comes from the `README.md` content of [`tediousjs/tedious-connection-pool`](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious-connection-pool).

[image]

So the solution to improve the network delay, as I known, there are several options you can consider to.

1. Make the region of your Azure SQL Database created close to your on-premise location as far as you can.
2. Migrate your node app to Azure Cloud service like WebApp to close to your Azure SQL Database, it will only spend your limited cost and it's up to your usage.
3. Try to use Azure VPN Gateway to reduce unnecessary network router jump.

Otherwise, there is another possible reason for timeout which be unexpected concurrent connection requirement. If that, I think you need to monitor this scenario and try to adjust the parameters of your connection pool configuration like `max`.